# Primal Forms text box to array

Tags: powershell

I am new to Primal Forms and am having trouble with data types of the form objects.  I am trying to use the text box for input (a list of servers in this case) and create an arry from that data to feed through a foreach loop (for instance, to test ping to each.

I have tried manually creating an array from the data as well as splitting it using the carriage return but I have had no luck.

Comment: I am also new to Primal Forms. Did you mean [Powershell Studio by SAPIEN](http://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio)?

Comment: No.  I created the form in Primal Forms CE.

Comment: Please add a link to the official product page. I cannot find it. Google search for primal forms leads to Powershell Studio. Is it SAPIEN at all?

Comment: http://www.sapien.com/software/communitytools  -  just down the page a bit.

Comment: Share your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.  It turns out it was simply an error with which the split command runs in Powershell 2.  Upgrading versions fixed the issue.